Alma Linux - nmcli " No suitable device found"
When I try to bring up a connection called wan0 with nmcli, I'm getting this error.
Wan0 is currently unplugged, want to get it configured before plugging it in.
I dont know why it's talking about enp2s0, that's not anywhere in the connection config
 nmcli con up wan0
Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection (device enp2s0 not available because profile is not compatible with device (mismatching interface name)).

My connections
nmcli c
NAME  UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE
lan0  d662827e-fac3-3069-9c71-d8e9ce1cb14a  ethernet  enp3s0f0
lo    71d6ab58-a026-4502-abf4-dcd3dda0de3a  loopback  lo
wan0  c82fe863-6953-49ee-9798-07544d44d530  ethernet  --

My devices
 nmcli d
DEVICE    TYPE      STATE                   CONNECTION
enp3s0f0  ethernet  connected               lan0
lo        loopback  connected (externally)  lo
enp2s0    ethernet  unavailable             --
enp3s0f1  ethernet  unavailable             --

I have the right interface name on the connection
nmcli c show wan0
connection.id:                          wan0
connection.uuid:                        c82fe863-6953-49ee-9798-07544d44d530
connection.stable-id:                   --
connection.type:                        802-3-ethernet
connection.interface-name:              enp3s0f1




As the error states, the device wan0 cannot be brought up because it doesn't have a device.

and as nmcli d shows, the device you want to use is unavailable (i.e., not there), so there's a problem on driver or hardware side.

Are there any pertinant log entries in dmesg relating to your wireless card? (Maybe missing firmware?)

Well, it turned out that this misleading message
meant that my network cable was unplugged.
